# extract components from SMD

Tags: components, surface-mount, pcb-assembly

I bought a cell phone in China (read chinese iphone), that despite the operational system is awful, when I opened to check the hardware and I found a not so bad hardware. I was able to extract microphone, motor, speaker and other interesting things. However there is an ARM processor that I couldn't remove. I'm a computer scientist (I had basic EE in the univeristy) and hobbyist. I'm able to extract components, when there is a solder to melt, but I never played with SMD. I found this [tool](http://www.chipquikinc.com/), but there is any other way to do it?

Comment: The ARM processor is likely to be a BGA package, running at high clock rates, with parallel memory interfaces for both RAM and Flash.  It's possible to remove it, but what do you expect to do with it?

Comment: that is another question :-)

Comment: Dude, you need to warn people before sending them through that chip quik link, I nearly went blind when the page rendered.  Must have been a sale on yellow the day they designed that page :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is a [Hot air rework station](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9PgwMzrk2g):

[image]

This uses a gentle stream of hot air (soldering iron temperature) to melt the solder and release the components.  Also, a "hot plate" can be beneficial when working with such components as BGA chips:

[image]

Failing that, put it in the oven face down and let the components fall off. (may not work depending on component size - the surface tension of the solder may well hold them in place).

Comment: Roughly, what is the availability and cost of that rework station?  dozens, hundreds, or thousands of $ or euros?  It may be far beyond the means of a hobbyist and tinkerer.

Comment: I have seen them on ebay for around £100, or for sale on places like Farnell for around £300 upwards.

Comment: @Daren - Hot-air rework stations run from hundreds of $ up through thousands for name-brand parts.  You can get a cheaper hot air gun from, for example, Harbor Freight very cheaply.  Sparkfun sells the [Heaterizer 3000 XL](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Tools/Heaterizer-Instructions-02.pdf) for $10. (It's underpowered, but works if you're patient.)

Comment: @KevinVermeer Class... Absolute class!  Seldom does a manual make me laugh out loud, but that one certainly did... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can extract (remove) the components with hot air - Majenko showed a pro tool, a paint-removing hot air gun can be the poor mans tool. Heat the board, give it a whack on the back, and a lot of components will fall of. BUT:

- survival of the components is not guaranteed (to put it mildly)
- even if they survided, could you do anything with them?
- did you check what that component, or something equivalent, would cost new (in other words, could it be worth the trouble?)

If the phone is a well known type there might be a development kit available somewhere on the web - but maybe only in Chinese :(

Comment: na, no dev kit, i looked around already :-(